# Manage a multilingual app

Tags: visual-studio, translation, multilingual

Actually I'm using App Multilingual Toolkit from Microsoft to manage translations from two different languages. I decided to translate it in Brazilian, so I'd like a friend from Brazil to translate of the strings for me. He hasbn't got any programming knowledge, Visual Studio tools and so on.

The question is how can I export from VS and pass him all the string in a readable format? Something that will be easy for me to import later as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of AMT, but I used the [gnu text translation toolkit](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html) ([Windows version](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gettext.htm)), which was very easy to use. You can use a webapp called [Pootle](http://sourceforge.net/projects/translate/?source=directory) that non-technical users can use to provide translated strings.

Users would update the strings via the website, which I could download an updated .po file from, this was then added to my deployment, using a little C# helper that read the strings and displayed the correct version depending on the user's language. It was remarkably easy all round, and as Gettext uses English words as the key, if you add a word that is not translated for a language you will get the English 'default' instead which is better than "error: word not defined" :)

IIRC I got into this because someone on the SVN team enabled the tool as a test, since then they've moved to [Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/) - I'm not sure if its significantly better as its a commercial web tool, but it might work for you.

That said, there's also Google translation toolkit - good luck getting to it as its now hidden behind Google's "one account login" guff.

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a utility software, appTranslator (http://www.apptranslator.com/), that helped a lot when trying to translate MFC programs.

It will not only help you translate the strings (STRINGTABLE) but will help you translate dialog content as well (update strings in dialogs, move resources if applicable, ... )

It has not been updated in a couple of years.

(just quickly tried it and it seems to work).

Answer (score 0):

I would say CSV is the most readable way to export/import